# Cannot Add Database to Superset

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, apache-superset

I am trying to configure Superset to read data from my Phoenix DB. I have added the [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) libs per the [instructions](https://superset.incubator.apache.org/installation.html#database-dependencies) but when I attempt to "Add Database" I get the following exception:

> The error message returned was:
> No module named 'base'

I don't see any messages in the superset.log so I'm at a loss on how to troubleshoot. Here's the list  of python modules in the venv

```
alembic (0.9.6)
amqp (1.4.9)
anyjson (0.3.3)
Babel (2.5.1)
billiard (3.3.0.23)
celery (3.1.23)
cffi (1.11.2)
click (6.7)
colorama (0.3.9)
cryptography (1.5.3)
defusedxml (0.5.0)
Flask (0.12.2)
Flask-AppBuilder (1.8.1)
Flask-Babel (0.11.2)
Flask-Cache (0.13.1)
Flask-Login (0.2.11)
Flask-Migrate (1.5.1)
Flask-OpenID (1.2.5)
Flask-Script (2.0.5)
Flask-SQLAlchemy (2.0)
Flask-Testing (0.5.0)
Flask-WTF (0.14.2)
future (0.16.0)
gunicorn (19.6.0)
humanize (0.5.1)
idna (2.6)
itsdangerous (0.24)
JayDeBeApi (1.1.1)
Jinja2 (2.10)
JPype1 (0.6.2)
kerberos (1.2.5)
kombu (3.0.37)
Mako (1.0.7)
Markdown (2.6.6)
MarkupSafe (1.0)
numpy (1.14.0rc1)
pandas (0.21.1)
parsedatetime (2.0)
phoenixdb (0.7)
pip (9.0.1)
protobuf (3.5.2)
pyasn1 (0.4.2)
pycparser (2.18)
pydruid (0.3.0)
PyGreSQL (5.0.3)
PyHive (0.5.0)
PyMySQL (0.7.9)
python-dateutil (2.5.3)
python-editor (1.0.3)
python3-openid (3.1.0)
pytz (2017.3)
requests (2.10.0)
sasl (0.2.1)
setuptools (38.5.2)
simplejson (3.8.2)
six (1.11.0)
SQLAlchemy (1.2.5)
sqlalchemy-phoenix (0.3.0)
SQLAlchemy-Utils (0.32.7)
sqlparse (0.1.19)
superset (0.15.0)
thrift (0.10.0)
thrift-sasl (0.3.0)
urllib-kerberos (0.2.0)
Werkzeug (0.11.10)
WTForms (2.1)
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: What version of Superset are you using? Does this happen when you try to save the database or when you click the plus sign to add any database?